# Extract words that meet a length condition from string

Tags: regex, r

I have a patent data set and when I import the IPC-class information to R I get a string containing whitespaces in a variable amount and a set of numbers I don't need. The following are the IPC codes corresponding to a patent file:

```
b <- "F24J   2/05        20060101AFI20150224BHEP        F24J   2/46        20060101ALI20150224BHEP        "
```

I would like to remove all whitespaces and that long alphanumeric string and just get the data I am interested in, obtaining a data frame like this, in this case:

```
m <- data.frame(matrix(c("F24J 2/05", "F24J 2/46"), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 1, ncol = 2))
m
```

I am trying with gsub, since I know that the long string will always have a length considerably longer than the data I am interested in:

```
x = gsub("\\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}\\b", "", ipc)
x
```

But I get stuck when I try to further clean this object in order to get the data frame I want. I am really stuck on this, and I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Instead of gsub, Try `strsplit(b, "\\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}\\s+")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_extract_all` from `stringr` package, provided you know the pattern you look for:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(b, "[A-Z]\\d{2}[A-Z] *\\d/\\d{2}")[[1]]
#[1] "F24J   2/05" "F24J   2/46"
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1, select all the noise data and remoe it using a sustitution:

```
/\s+|\w{5,}/g
```

(Spaces and 'long' words)

https://regex101.com/r/lG4dC4/1

---

Option 2, select all the short words (length max 4):

```
/\b\S{4}\b/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/fZ8mH5/1

Answer (score 0):

or…

```
library(stringi)
library(readr)

read_fwf(paste0(stri_match_all_regex(b, "[[:alnum:][:punct:][:blank:]]{50}")[[1]][,1], collapse="\n"),
         fwf_widths(c(7, 12, 31)))[,1:2]

##     X1   X2
## 1 F24J 2/05
## 2 F24J 2/46
```

(this makes the assumption - from only seeing 2 'records' - that each 'record' is 50 characters long)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach to akie the amtrix using **qdapRegex** (I maintain this package) + **magrittr**'s pipeline:

```
library(qdapRegex); library(magrittr)

b %>%
    rm_white_multiple() %>%
    rm_default(pattern="F[0-9A-Z]+\\s\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}", extract=TRUE) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    strsplit("\\s") %>%
    do.call(rbind, .)

##      [,1]   [,2]  
## [1,] "F24J" "2/05"
## [2,] "F24J" "2/46"
```